# Why does Linux not allow deletion of read only directory?

Tags: permissions, directory

I am new to Linux. When I make a file as read only I am still able to delete that file. I read on the net that deleting a file depends upon the permissions of the folder in which it lies.

To make things clear let's say I have a directory test(with all permissions) in which I have a read only file 'abc.txt'. Even if this file is read only I can easily delete it.

Now consider the case where I have a subdirectory named 'sub' under test. This directory is read only. When I want to delete this subdirectory it throws an error saying that can't delete this directory.

In linux a directory is also treated as a file. But the behaviour differs for read only files vs read only directories.

What's the reason for this?

Comment: Have you tried deleting a directory and file that lives in a read-only directory?

Comment: "Why this thing does not depend on the parent directory?" Who said it doesn't?

Comment: Please improve the wording of your question. To me it sounds a bit confusing, not that clear what you're asking. As far as I know you're not allowed to delete a directory if it's parent is read-only either.

Comment: "When I want to delete this subdirectory" How? Is the directory empty?

Comment: Even with the edit, I cannot understand your question and reproduce your claim. My guess is that you try to `rmdir` a *non-empty* directory

Comment: What are the exact commands you enter and their output?

Comment: Without *exact commands* your question is unclear (or wrong)

Comment: @muru the directory that I was trying to delete was non empty. That was causing the error.

Comment: Please try to put useful information in your question. What command are you using ? how are you using it ? to whom the file belong to ? answer those question and I might vote reopen

Comment: The fact that your directory was non-empty should be written in your question, not as a comment

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because Unix was defined that way, and POSIX requires that behavior. And Linux tries to be Unix & POSIX compliant.

You might have some misconception about what [files](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_file) are (caveat, there are not exactly the same on Unix and on Windows). BTW, they matter for many [system calls](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_call) (listed in [syscalls(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/link.2.html)), with several system calls giving a [file descriptor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_descriptor) from a file path (see also [path_resolution(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/path_resolution.7.html)). In contrast to some other OSes, a file (on Linux or Unix or POSIX systems) has not only *one* name (or [path](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_(computing))): some files have no names, others have several ones; indeed most files have one name.

Remember that files are an [abstraction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstraction_(software_engineering)) provided to [user-space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_space) (and [applications](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_software) -including [utility](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Utility_software) programs- running in [processes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_(computing))) by the [operating system kernel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_(operating_system)). And system calls are the only way for programs (and processes running them) to interact with the kernel.

<sup>Your disk does not know about files (but your OS does). A disk contains simply blocks of bytes. It is your OS which understands them as files</sup>

A file is (on Unix & Linux) an [inode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inode). See also [inode(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/inode.7.html). The inode contains meta-data about that file (which you could query with [stat(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/stat.2.html), 
`fstat`  etc...) -including type, creation time, permissions, ownership, size, etc...- and contains (or more often points to) the file data (a sequence of bytes).

> But deleting a read only directory poses no problem.

A [directory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directory_(computing)) is a special kind of file (there are other kinds of files than plain files and directories, e.g. [fifo(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/fifo.7.html)-s, [symlink(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/symlink.7.html)-s, etc). It contains a dictionary mapping strings to inodes. How that happens is specific to every file system type. Use [opendir(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/opendir.3.html) (and later `closedir`) and [readdir(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/readdir.3.html) to read it.

> .... permissions of of the folder in which it lies...

Misconception. Folders do not exit on Linux (they are a [GUI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphical_user_interface) artefact *sometimes* displayed by your [desktop environment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Desktop_environment)), you probably are talking of directories. [File systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_system) contains various kind of files (including directories and symbolic links).

A given inode can appear in *several* directories (you might say that a file could have *several* paths, then they all have the same "power" and similar "role"). Use the [link(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/link.2.html) system call -perhaps via the [ln(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ln.1.html) command- for adding some additional path to a file. Use the [unlink(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/unlink.2.html) system call for removing a path to a file. In some cases, an inode can exist without appearing in any directory. A common case (used for implementing temporary files) is when you create a file -e.g. using [creat(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/creat.2.html) or `open` then `unlink` (or [remove(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/remove.3.html)) that file just after (e.g. in the same process, but perhaps not).

When an inode becomes unreachable (because there is no open file descriptor to it, and because it is no more mentioned in some directory) the kernel removes that inode (and the data blocks related to it).

When you "remove" a file (e.g. using the [rm(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/rm.1.html) utility), the `/bin/rm` program (and the process running that command) is just using `unlink` (and you are writing into a directory containing some mapping between names and inodes). If nothing more "points to" that inode, indeed it gets removed. Since the kernel is writing into a directory, it requires your process to have write permission for that. See also [credentials(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/credentials.7.html).

A directory needs [mkdir(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mkdir.2.html) to be made, and [rmdir(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/rmdir.2.html) to be removed (from its parent): if you use [unlink(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/unlink.2.html) to remove it, that would fail with `EISDIR`. But [rmdir(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/rmdir.2.html) requires the directory to be empty (because the kernel requires the file hierarchy to be a [direct acyclic graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_acyclic_graph), and [circular references](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_reference) are forbidden, by some kind of [reference counting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference_counting)). Both `mkdir` and `rmdir` syscalls handle the magic  `.` and `..` entries of directories.

> But deleting a read only directory poses no problem. Why this thing does not depend on the parent directory?

It does in general (but [sticky bit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sticky_bit) on directories has some specific meaning).

#### about edited question

In your edited question, you claim (incorrectly, or else some important detail is missing):

> Now consider the case where I have a subdirectory named `sub` under `test`. This directory is read only. When I want to delete this subdirectory it throws an error saying that can't delete this directory.

**I cannot reproduce your claim** (please provide some [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)). For readability, I am considering directories `testdir` and `subdir` instead of your names (but that does not change anything; however your `test` is confusable with [test(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/test.1.html))

```
 % /bin/mkdir testdir
 % /bin/mkdir testdir/subdir
 % /bin/ls -la testdir
total 12
drwxr-xr-x 3 basile basile 4096 Apr 24 13:09 .
drwxr-xr-x 6 basile basile 4096 Apr 24 13:08 ..
drwxr-xr-x 2 basile basile 4096 Apr 24 13:09 subdir
 % /bin/chmod a-w testdir/subdir
 % /bin/ls -la testdir          
total 12
drwxr-xr-x 3 basile basile 4096 Apr 24 13:09 .
drwxr-xr-x 6 basile basile 4096 Apr 24 13:08 ..
dr-xr-xr-x 2 basile basile 4096 Apr 24 13:09 subdir
 % /bin/rmdir testdir/subdir  
 % /bin/ls -la testdir      
total 8
drwxr-xr-x 2 basile basile 4096 Apr 24 13:14 .
drwxr-xr-x 6 basile basile 4096 Apr 24 13:08 ..
```

Remember that [rmdir(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/rmdir.1.html) (it uses the [rmdir(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/rmdir.2.html) system call) require the removed directory to be empty, and some files (whose name starts with a dot) could be "hidden" by your shell or by `ls`. List all files of the removed directory with `ls -a`

---

You might read [*Operating Systems: Three Easy Pieces*](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~remzi/OSTEP/)

Comment: Note that removing a directory implies unlinking the `.` and `..` entries in it prior to unlinking the directory from its parent, so means _modifying_ the directory first. Historically, [that was done in user space](https://github.com/v7unix/v7unix/blob/master/v7/usr/src/cmd/rmdir.c#L80). But `rmdir` was setuid root, so you still didn't need write permission to the directory, `rmdir` only checked that you had write access to the parent. Nowadays, that unlinking of `.` and `..` (for FSs that do have real directory entries for them) is done in the kernel as part of the rmdir() system call.

Comment: @Basile sorry my question was not formulated in the right way. I have edited it to make it more clear. Please have a look.

Comment: TL,DR: To remove a non-empty subdirectory (as in the question) requires one to empty the subdirectory first, which requires modifying the subdirectory and hence the `w` permission. That's why a non-empty read-only directory cannot be removed with `rm -rf`.

Answer (score 4):

No, you cannot remove a directory if its parent directory is read-only.
Try it for yourself:

```
$ cd /tmp
$ mkdir -p /tmp/readonly1/readonly2
$ chmod 555 /tmp/readonly1/readonly2 /tmp/readonly1   # dr-xr-xr-x
$ rmdir /tmp/readonly1/readonly2
rmdir: failed to remove '/tmp/readonly1/readonly2': Permission denied
```

Removing with force won't help either:

```
$ rm -rf /tmp/readonly1/readonly2
rm: cannot remove '/tmp/readonly1/readonly2': Permission denied
$ rm -rf /tmp/readonly1
rm: cannot remove '/tmp/readonly1/readonly2': Permission denied
$ chmod 755 /tmp/readonly1/readonly2  # drwxr-xr-x
$ rm -rf /tmp/readonly1
rm: cannot remove '/tmp/readonly1/readonly2': Permission denied
```

But as soon as you make the `readonly1` directory writeable, you can remove its sub-directory `readonly2`:

```
$ chmod 555 /tmp/readonly1/readonly2  # dr-xr-xr-x
$ chmod 755 /tmp/readonly1            # drwxr-xr-x
$ rmdir /tmp/readonly1/readonly2
$ rmdir /tmp/readonly1        #... or just rm -rf /tmp/readonly1 all at once
$ ls /tmp/readonly1
ls: cannot access '/tmp/readonly1': No such file or directory
```

Comment: That does not explain why a read-only file can be removed.

Comment: And that is not what the original poster asked, if you read more than the title of the question.

Comment: The original poster's question *does* seem a bit confused, so it's probably a good thing you covered that part. Let the votes fall as they may.

Comment: @telcoM U didn't answer my question. Whatever u said I already knew that.

Comment: Well, then I misinterpreted your question, sorry about that. I hope Basile's answer was more useful to you then.

Comment: @telcoM sorry my question was not formulated in the right way. I have edited it to make it more clear. Please have a look.

Comment: On my system, I can delete a read-only directory just fine, i.e. a read-only directory behaves the same as a read-only file. So there must be something different in your set-up. What is the filesystem type you're using? Which Linux distribution and version? Are you using SELinux or some other "extra" access control system? ... ah, I see, you tried to delete a non-empty directory.